# EditTextPreference value only refreshed after clicking ListPreference second time

Tags: android, refresh, listpreference

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now so I decided to ask here what I' m doing wrong.

First of all:
- I have a PreferenceFragment with a ListPreference on top and an EditTextPreference below
- The ListPreference is filled with Objects, the values are stored in a file and read from there (this works flawlessly)
- The EditTextPreference should display the value of the in the ListPreference chosen object. And that's the problem: after choosing the value nothing changes so I have to click the ListPreference once more and the value is set correctly. Is this a problem with my Listener?

Here's the code:

```
public class SettingsTestFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private final String[] pref_key_array = {"pref_key_lp", "pref_key_et""}; // array that contains all the preference keys of changeable values
    private final int numberOfEntries = pref_key_array.length;
    private Preference[] pref_entries;
    String[] entries = {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"};
    String[] entryValues = {"0", "1", "2"};
    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        final SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        final EditTextPreference et = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("pref_key_et");
        final ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_key_lp");
        prepareListPref(lp);
        pref_entries = new Preference[numberOfEntries];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
            pref_entries[i] = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(pref_key_array[i]);
        }


        lp.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                position = Integer.valueOf(myPreference.getString("pref_key_lp", "0"));
                et.setText(entries[position]);
                return true;
            }
        });


        Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener changeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                position = Integer.valueOf(myPreference.getString("pref_key_lp", "0"));
                preference.setSummary(entries[position]);
                return true;
            }
        };
         lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
       updateSummary(key, pref_key_array, numberOfEntries, pref_entries);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up listener when a key changes
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
            updateSummary(pref_key_array[i], pref_key_array, numberOfEntries, pref_entries);
        }
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Unregister listener every time a key changes
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void prepareListPref(ListPreference lp) {
        lp.setEntries(entries);
        lp.setEntryValues(entryValues);
        lp.setDefaultValue("0");
    }

    public void updateSummary(String key, String[] pref_key_array, int numberOfEntries, Preference[] pref_entries) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
            if(key.equals(pref_key_array[i])) {
                if(pref_entries[i] instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                    final EditTextPreference currentPreference = (EditTextPreference) pref_entries[i];
                    pref_entries[i].setSummary(currentPreference.getText());
                } else if(pref_entries[i] instanceof ListPreference) {
                    final ListPreference currentPreference = (ListPreference) pref_entries[i];
                    pref_entries[i].setSummary(currentPreference.getEntry());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing the code for reading from the file and writing the value to the Settings works but only after clicking the ListPreference a second time. Do you have any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "setTitle" on the EditTextPreference instead? I think the "setText" is for the editable part of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the problem is that the new value is only accessible after opening the ListPrefrence the second time so setTitle() doesn't change anything. Could I "simulate" the opening of the LP to get the new value?

Comment: But you can already get the value from the key of the listPreference, so why not use it instead?

Comment: I also don't get why you wish to use both EditText and ListPreference, if both should show the same value. Why not let the ListPreference have one of its items to be "Custom", and show a dialog of entering what you wish there?

Comment: Well, the Java class above is very simplified. In my project the ListPreference is filled dynamically and are profiles the user can edit. The EditTextPreference above is just symbolically for all the other parameters. 
The problem is that i can NOT get the value from the key because the value gets refreshed after pressing the ListPreference a second time. So I stripped down the class to its minimum to make it easier to understand and find the error. :) 
I know something's wrong but it can't be too bad because it's (nearly) working. Thanks

Comment: ok, you don't want to change the UI, but I don't understand the problem. As I understood, you want the EditTextPreference to have the same value as on the ListPreference. So what I suggested is that on the initialization get the value from the key of the ListPreference and put it there, and also change the value by yourself each time it gets changed on the list. should cover all cases this way.

Comment: Hm, I might have explained it badly: the class above is very simplified. In the real class I'm using in my app there will be up to 90 Preferences split up to 3 PreferenceFragments. In the ListPreference the user can chosse between his created profiles and each profiles has 90 values. After changing the ListView the values of the chosen profile should be "loaded" into the EditTextPreferences. And I want to simulate this with the class above.

Comment: ok, I will try to make something, but have you also considered making your own customized preference class ? It could be better instead of making so many couples of preferences that are tied this way.

Comment: Please try the code I've written and tell me if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'm not sure what you are trying to do and what is the problem, so I've made a sample, showing the next thing:

1. a listPreference that its default value&entry will set the title&summary of an EditTextPreference .
2. when choosing an item on the ListPreference, it will also update tge title&summary of the EditTextPreference according to the value&entry of the item being selected.
3. Not sure what to do with the EditTextPreference. This is your choice.

I still think you should consider making a custom Preference class, as you wrote that you intend to use a lot of couples of ListPreference&EditTextPreference.

BTW, code is based on an app that I've made (link [**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)). I've made it so that it will be easy to handle multiple listPreferences easier.

Here's the code:

**res/values/strings_activity_settings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="pref__custom_app_theme" translatable="false">pref__custom_app_theme</string>
    <string name="pref__app_theme" translatable="false">pref__app_theme</string>

    <string-array name="pref__app_theme_entries">
        <item>@string/cards_light</item>
        <item>@string/cards_dark</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="pref__app_theme__cards_ui" translatable="false">CARDS_UI</string>
    <string name="pref__app_theme__cards_ui_dark" translatable="false">CARDS_UI_DARK</string>
    <string name="pref__app_theme_default" translatable="false">@string/pref__app_theme__cards_ui</string>


    <string-array name="pref__app_theme_values">
        <item>@string/pref__app_theme__cards_ui</item>
        <item>@string/pref__app_theme__cards_ui_dark</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**res/values/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="app_theme">App Theme</string>
    <string name="cards_light">cards light</string>
    <string name="cards_dark">cards dark</string>
</resources>
```

**res/xml/pref_general.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- theme -->
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref__app_theme_default"
        android:entries="@array/pref__app_theme_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref__app_theme_values"
        android:key="@string/pref__app_theme"
        android:title="@string/app_theme"/>

    <EditTextPreference android:key="@string/pref__custom_app_theme"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
  {
  public interface IOnListPreferenceChosenListener
    {
    public void onChosenPreference(String key,String entry,String value);
    }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    final EditTextPreference editTextPreference=(EditTextPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref__custom_app_theme));
    final ListPreference listPreference=prepareListPreference(this,R.string.pref__app_theme,R.array.pref__app_theme_entries,R.array.pref__app_theme_values,R.string.pref__app_theme_default,new IOnListPreferenceChosenListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onChosenPreference(final String key,final String entry,final String value)
          {
          editTextPreference.setTitle(value);
          editTextPreference.setSummary(entry);
          }
      });
    editTextPreference.setTitle(listPreference.getValue());
    editTextPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntry());
    }

  public static ListPreference prepareListPreference(final PreferenceActivity activity,final int prefKeyId,//
      final int entriesId,final int valuesId,final int defaultValueId,final IOnListPreferenceChosenListener listener)
    {
    final String prefKey=activity.getString(prefKeyId);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final ListPreference pref=(ListPreference)activity.findPreference(prefKey);
    final String[] entries=activity.getResources().getStringArray(entriesId);
    final String[] values=activity.getResources().getStringArray(valuesId);
    final String defaultValue=activity.getResources().getString(defaultValueId);
    final String currentValue=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity).getString(prefKey,defaultValue);
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;++i)
      {
      final String value=values[i];
      if(TextUtils.equals(currentValue,value))
        {
        pref.setSummary(entries[i]);
        pref.setValueIndex(i);
        break;
        }
      }
    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener()
      {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference,final Object newValue)
          {
          final String newValueStr=newValue.toString();
          String entryChosen=null;
          for(int i=0;i<values.length;++i)
            {
            final String value=values[i];
            if(TextUtils.equals(newValueStr,value))
              {
              entryChosen=entries[i];
              break;
              }
            }
          pref.setSummary(entryChosen);
          if(listener!=null)
            listener.onChosenPreference(prefKey,entryChosen,newValueStr);
          return true;
          }
      });
    return pref;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code! It works really well with your values but I want to test it with my profile managment before accepting it as the answer to my problem. Anyway I really want to think you for your help until this point! I'll give my final feedback in a day or two.

Comment: What do you mean by "with my profile management" ? you can put any values and strings you wish. It's just a sample...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to see if I could implement your code into my exisiting project, the profile names are stored in an ArrayList which is generated dynamically. These names are the entries in the ListPreference and what should I say? It works perfectly! Thank you for your help and your patience!

Comment: @user1318160 You're welcomed. May I look at the app you are working on? You can try mine too (which this code was taken from) .

Comment: The app is currently in making and it will takes some time (probably a few months as it is made in my free time) until it's complete. But I'll take a look at your app and will rate it in the Play Store.